# Slowness while using NFS shares on kubernetes

Tags: database, kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I have a K8s-Cluster running which had some Pods/Statefulsets running PostgreSQL.

As PersistenVolumes I only have a NFS-Shares. Now the performance of the PostgreSQL is getting slower.

Can it be related to the fact I'm using NFS-Shares?

What should I use instead?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use, how did you deploy it? Did the solution of Chandra Sekar help you?

Comment: The version of the server is 1.18.10. 
The Answer of Chandra was helpful. I will test it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it could be one of the reason since it is network file system, any glitches or high load could performance issue with the underlying application and it is always best to use the block storage like Ceph, amazon ebs etc.